# Como remover o nome do aplicativo "app_name" da toolbar?

Tags: java, android

Estou começando no mundo Android, e estou desenvolvendo um projeto pessoal pra apromorar meu conhecimentos, mas me deparei com um problema, eu defini o thema do meu app para:

```
<style name="Theme.ControleCartao" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

Assim eu posso criar a minha própria Toolbar personalizada.

Aqui está o código da minha toolbar no momento:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_mainactivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/azul"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titulo_mainactivity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:text="@string/titulo_mainactivity"
            android:textColor="@color/branco"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

E no arquivo .java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_mainactivity);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

Meu AndroidManifest está assim:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.ControleCartao">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Porém, quando executo o app, ele fica com dois títulos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O título que está em branco foi eu que criei junto com a toolbar, o que está em preto é o nome do app. Não sei como retirar o nome do app, já tentei excluir o label do manifest, mas ele também exclui o nome da lista de apps instalados no celular, então, se alguém puder me ajudar, ficarei grato!

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

você pode resolver esse problema programaticamente, adicionando a seguinte linha após declarar qual será a **SupportActionBar**:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Então, sua MainActivity ficará assim:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_mainactivity);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo!